# Qué significa LTS

Tags: ubuntu

Estoy descargando una versión de ubuntu pero dice Ubuntu 18.04.1

```
LTS
```

.

> ¿Alguién sabe que significa LTS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las siglas **lts** hacen referencia a `long time support` "soporte de largo plazo".

Para una mayor compresión te incluyo **[un link de wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soporte_de_largo_plazo)** donde podrás ver el lts de cada so!

Comment: Muy amable, eso quiere decir que la versión **Ubuntu 18.10**, no tiene soporte a largo plazo puesto que no tiene las siglas `LTS`

Comment: exacto de momento solo la 18.4 las 18.10 es preview se descontinua al salir la siguiente!